# How can I recursively extend a list of paths?

Tags: python, recursion

Sorry for being a bit unspecific in the title.

**Explanation:**

So I got a list `paths`, and I apply

```py
for path in paths:
    references = GetReferences(path)
```

Now I have to apply `GetReferences()` again on every reference in `references`, and so on until no further references appear.
Then I need to return the whole list of `changedFiles` and all references that appeared recursively.

**Example:**

I have 4 objects A, B, C and D.
A references B (A <-> B) and B references C and D (B <-> C, D).
`paths` consists of A.
When I apply `GetReferences()` on A, I will end up with B. Now I have to apply `GetReferences()` on B again, which will give me C and D. Now the references of C and D have to be resolved. This will need to go on until no further references can be found. Then I need the whole list of base objects and referenced objects, so in this particular case the return list would be A, B, C, D.

I couldn't manage to write an elegant function that effectively does what I need. It has to be memory and time-effective, because the list of paths could be enormous. I hope you can comprehend my problem, and thanks in advance of any helpful answers.

I tried to write a recursive function that is memory and time-effective, but I always ended up in an indefinite loop.

Here is a piece of code I've tried, it is not functional because I used the last hour to play around with it.

```py
references = []

def fetch_references(paths):
    for path in paths:
        try:
            refs = GetReferences(path)
            references.extend(refs)
        except:
            pass
    
    if len(references) > 0:
        paths.extend(fetch_references(references))
    return paths
```

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre].

Comment: Edited the post, I hope this example is sufficient.

Comment: Can `GetReferences` return a path that has already been visited (in other words: do you references from a tree or a more general graph)? Also, please provide the code you have tried so far.

Comment: It can return a path that has been already visited when 2 different objects reference the same. But that isn't a matter because the return list will be distinct, I just need the list of unique paths.

Comment: @jvmpman The example isn't sufficient because it does not include the implementation of `GetReferences`. At the very least, you should include a dummy class/function that replicates the essential behaviour. Also, you should provide some sample input along with the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for a breadth-first traversal algorithm:

```
paths = [start]
visited = set()
while paths:
    visited.update(paths)
    paths = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(GetReferences(path) for path in paths))
    paths -= visited
return visited
```

There are other ways of implementing this, such as with a queue, which will have a lower memory footprint for graphs with a high branching factor. Ultimately if you are very concerned by performance, don't use Python.